# 000webhost : URLs of my site seems not working

Tags: php, web-hosting

I have the following site created and hosted on 000webhost.com
[Click Here to visit the site](http://doit-tech.tk/)

The problem is the index page loads correctly and fine, but I have set navigation links of **header.php** to load through a controller called **pages.php**, since I cannot call direct URLs of the views. It works fine in my localhost, but when I hosted it, it leads me no where. Please help me to solve this.

My config.php

```
<?php 

$config['base_url'] = 'http://doit-tech.tk/'; // Base URL including trailing slash (e.g. http://localhost/)

$config['default_controller'] = 'main'; // Default controller to load
$config['error_controller'] = 'error'; // Controller used for errors (e.g. 404, 500 etc)

$config['db_host'] = 'mysql5.000webhost.com'; // Database host (e.g. localhost)
$config['db_name'] = '********'; // Database name
$config['db_username'] = '*******'; // Database username
$config['db_password'] = '*******'; // Database password

?>
```

My header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Welcome to PIP</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="author" content="">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>static/css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="level gradient shadowmkr">
         <div class="headerarea">
            <div class="col4"><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>static/images/DoIT Logo.png" width="300" height="75" /></div>
            <div class="col8">
               <div id="nav">
                  <div id="nav_wrapper">
                     <ul>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>pages/viewpage/index">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#">COURSES</a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>pages/viewpage/course-java-programming">Java Programming with Software Engineering Concepts</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>pages/viewpage/course-web-designing">Web Designing for Beginners</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Web Application Development with PHP &amp; MySQL</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>pages/viewpage/course-qa-pm">Software QA &amp; Project Management</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Computer &amp; IT for Beginners</a>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#">SOLUTIONS</a>
                           <ul>
                              <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                              </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                              </li>

                           </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li> <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>pages/viewpage/contact-us">CONTACT US</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
                  <!-- Nav wrapper end -->
               </div>
               <!-- Nav end -->
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

My pages.php controller

```
<?php

class Pages extends Controller {

    function index()
    {

    }

    function viewpage($page){

       $template = $this->loadView($page);
       $template->render();

    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Is this going to be your website? You have courses on programming, including PHP and MySQL but you can't do this yourself? How are you linking everything together? How are you calling your `Pages` class and it looks like `config.php` is not included in `header.php`.

Comment: @putvande I guess you have not worked in an MVC architecture, <li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>pages/viewpage/course-java-programming"> calls the "pages.php" controller and passes "course-java-programming" to "viewpage" function as the parameter, and you do not have to include config.php in every page explicitly since you define it in your index page, I recon you would have to follow one of my courses to know the basics. :)

Answer (score -2):

I don't see pages.php called anywhere, either you ment to pass the page as a parameter to pages.php as such:

```
http://doit-tech.tk/pages.php?/viewpage/course-web-designing
```

Or pages.php is supposed to exist at the folder as a default page like index but does not exist:

```
http://doit-tech.tk/pages/viewpage/course-web-designing/pages.php
```

Also base url is not needed if staying in your domain, relative paths are much easier than absolute.

Comment: pages.php is not a view but a controller as I have mentioned above, so you cannot see it by simply through the URL